# Replace link urls with # serverside

Tags: php

I wish to replace all the link urls in some HTML with a number sign (#).

The following basically works, however, it to my dismay inserts a `<!DOCTYPE>`, `<html>`, and `<body>` tag around the modified HTML.  Is it possible to keep these tags from being inserted?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

```
$html_with_urls = '<p>hello.  Here is a <a href="http://somesite.com">link</a>.  Goodby</p>';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Temorarily disable errors resulting from improperly formed HTML
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_with_urls);
$a = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($a as $link) {
    if ($link->hasAttribute('href')) {
        $link->setAttribute('href', '#');
    }
}
$html_without_urls = $doc->saveHTML();
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
echo($html_with_urls . '<br />' . $html_without_urls);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, `DOMDocument` class has got no option to keep it from adding those extra stuffs. It returns a complete and a valid HTML.

For your particular case, you could strip those contents off the document yourself:
*[From the code you could tell when it wont work :)]*

```
$html_without_urls = str_replace(array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $html_without_urls);
$html_without_urls = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/i', '', $html_without_urls);
echo $html_without_urls;
```

---

Or if you could do with some 3rd party libraries, you could use [SmartDOMDocumet](http://beerpla.net/projects/smartdomdocument-a-smarter-php-domdocument-class/). Just call the function `saveHTMLExact()` instead.

Comment: -1 for suggesting the use of Regex to modify HTML. In a DOMDocuemnt related question, no less!

Comment: I disagree. I am not using regex over raw HTML; rather Im using it over a string, whose structure is well known. (DOMDocument's saveHTML always returns a valid HTML with doctype)

Comment: Looks like SmartDOMDOcument::saveHTMLExact() does exactly what I want, but will probably use your Regex solution so I don't need to deal with a 3rd party library.  Thanks!

Comment: SmartDOMDocument uses regex. Indeed, these two lines *could* have been copied straight from SmartDOMDocument -- this is exactly how it is done in that library. For reference, to remove those wrappers without regex (which I think is bad practice no matter **WHAT**), you use: `$doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild); $doc->replaceChild($doc->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $doc->firstChild);` I will stick with my -1.